# Why is this simple rewrite falling to 500 server error?

Tags: .htaccess

I have my own sandbox/testing system and I want to rewrite `g/something` to `g/something.php`

I used this very easy rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^g/(.*?)[^\.]+ g/$1.php [L]
```

Questions:

- How can I negate my rule? (It means that this rule will trigger only when requested file isn't ending with `.php`. I have tried `(^\.php)`, `(!\.php)` but nothing worked, so I used `[^\.]`.
- Why is this line throwing 500 Internal server error?

Error log:

```
[Sat Aug 20 15:47:53 2011] [error] [client myip] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRec
[Sat Aug 20 15:47:53 2011] [debug] core.c(3063): [client myip] r->uri = /g/..........php
[Sat Aug 20 15:47:53 2011] [debug] core.c(3069): [client myip] redirected from r->uri = /g/.........php
[Sat Aug 20 15:47:53 2011] [debug] core.c(3069): [client myip] redirected from r->uri = /g/........php
[Sat Aug 20 15:47:53 2011] [debug] core.c(3069): [client myip] redirected from r->uri = /g/.......php
[Sat Aug 20 15:47:53 2011] [debug] core.c(3069): [client myip] redirected from r->uri = /g/......php
[Sat Aug 20 15:47:53 2011] [debug] core.c(3069): [client myip] redirected from r->uri = /g/.....php
[Sat Aug 20 15:47:53 2011] [debug] core.c(3069): [client myip] redirected from r->uri = /g/....php
[Sat Aug 20 15:47:53 2011] [debug] core.c(3069): [client myip] redirected from r->uri = /g/...php
[Sat Aug 20 15:47:53 2011] [debug] core.c(3069): [client myip] redirected from r->uri = /g/..php
[Sat Aug 20 15:47:53 2011] [debug] core.c(3069): [client myip] redirected from r->uri = /g/.php
[Sat Aug 20 15:47:53 2011] [debug] core.c(3069): [client myip] redirected from r->uri = /g/64002
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^g/(.*?)[^\.]+
```

matches your replacement, because it's e.g. `g/test.php` which is `g/`, then `test.ph` and then `p` which does not include a `.`. So the replacement is replaced again, etc. As a result, there is an overflow of redirects (look at the Apache error log).

You probably want:

```
^g/([^.]*?)$
```

since that matches `g/`, then anything without a dot, and then **the end of the URL** to make sure it matches the exact URL.

Comment: 1. how can I negate  regexp without using [] but with ()?
2. how is it possible that this works?

Comment: Negating: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteRule. So `!^...$`. The solution works because the replacement does *not* match the regexp again.

Comment: Thanks. And when I would like to rewrite g/test/2 to g/test-2.php, what would I use?

Comment: Alternative solution (which is easier to understand for those who are not that good with regex **plus** it will allow rewrite URLs that DO contain a dot, e.g. `/g/something.here`): `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$` `RewriteRule ^g/(.+)$ g/$1.php [L]`

Comment: @genesis: Perhaps `^g/([^.]*?)'([^.]*?)$ g/$1-$2.php`.

Comment: @pimvdb: ' ? I have never seen ' in regexp

Comment: @genesis: My keyboard was displaying incorrect keys (Windows automatically swaps my keyboard language at odds...). I meant a hyphen of course.